# Certification - wall-plug power supplies

Tags: power-supply, power

We manufacture small electronic products that use a wall plug power supply (100-240 International input to 5VDC 15W output - a "wall wart"). We want to change to a 20 watt wall plug power supply. Both power supplies have full International certifications as does our products. Do we need to re-certify anything when switching to the 20 watt supply?

Comment: The internationally recognized universal supply range is 85 volts to 265 volts.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want/need to recheck your EMC compliance, as I've seen different PSUs generate radically different levels of noise, and depending on your equipment design this may well impact emissions.

In terms of safety certs, it depends on how the existing kit is specified.

With an external PSU, which can be separated by the end-user, you pretty much have to have separate certs for the PSU and powered equipment.  In that case changing the PSU should not require recert of the main equipment.  However, if the increased power supply is because of changes inside the equipment, you might need to revisit both.